# How do we define a functional derivative?

Tags: functional-equations, calculus-of-variations

I’m studying variational principles, and have come across the expression for a functional derivative, defined (in this case at least) by  $\delta F = \int\left\{\delta y (\delta F[y]/\delta y)\right\}dx$. I  don't understand where this comes from (and how it works) as the LHS and RHS clearly don't "balance". I know this is a bit vague but any help would be  really appreciated, thanks! (Here $F[y]=\int f(y,y',x)dx$ ).

Comment: It can help clarify issues  if you look at the function $\phi:t \to F[ y+tz]$ mapping $ \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $\phi:t \mapsto  F[ y+tz]$, where $z$ is another function in the domain of $F$, or in the linear span of the domain of $F$.  With luck, you can find a formula for $\phi'(0)$ in terms of $z$; with better luck $\phi'(0)=\int g(x)z(x)\,dx$ for some $g$ which is in a sense your desired $\delta F/\delta y$.  The key thing here is $\phi'(0)$ depends linearly in the function $z$.

Comment: There's a nice derivation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Formula). There's also one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler.E2.80.93Lagrange_equation), which follows the more "classical" derivation as the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks both of you those pages are helpful!